# how t find second greatest digit in a number ? Python

Tags: python-2.7

The Program must take a number and print the second largest digit in the number.

```
i have tried this ==>
a=raw_input("Please enter the nummber =")
l=list()
for i in a:
    l.append(int(i))
great=0
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    for j in l:
        if l[i]>j:
            if l[i]>great:
                great=l[i]
print great
for i in range(20):
    great-=1
    for j in l:
        if j==great:
            print "Second largest number is ",j
            break
```

But this gave Output

```
Please enter the nummber =1459
9
Second largest number is  5
Second largest number is  4
Second largest number is  1
```

Comment: You did a good job in explaining the scenario and demonstrating what you have tried and what the output is.  It would be even better if you also wrote what you had expected the output to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this easily accomplished using the build-in function of python [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

once you have the number from `raw_input` you can do this

```
>>> a
'1459'
>>> ordnum = sorted(map(int,a),reverse=True)
>>> ordnum[1]
5
>>> ordnum
[9, 5, 4, 1]
>>>
```

first with map convert every digit to a number, and result is passed to sorted that order them in ascending order by default, but with the `reverse` key-word argument the orden is reversed, then you get a list with the digit in order so the second elements is the desire digit.

Or as you already do the *map* part, you can do the sort part directly to the list

```
>>> l
[1, 4, 5, 9]
>>> l.sort(reverse=True)
>>> l
[9, 5, 4, 1]
>>>
```

to the same efect.

The problem with your code is that you don't break the first for-loop, only the second, to break both you can do as @cjahangir show, or make that into a function that return when find it like this

```
def second_great(great,num):
    for i in range(10):
        great -= 1
        for j in num:
            if j == great:
                return j
```

and call it as

```
print great
print "Second largest number is ", second_great(great,l)
```

---

as pointed out by @Blckknght, the conversion to int is unneeded in this case because the digit are order correctly when handled individually, also you can use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to remove repetitions in any of the versions.

```
>>> b="1459934"
>>> sorted(b,reverse=True)
['9', '9', '5', '4', '4', '3', '1']
>>> sorted(set(b),reverse=True)
['9', '5', '4', '3', '1']
>>> sorted(map(int,set(b)),reverse=True)
[9, 5, 4, 3, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: I'd point out that you don't need to convert single-digit strings to integers in order for them to sort correctly. It's only different-length number strings that have issues when sorted lexicographically (e.g. `"10"` coming before `"2"`).

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
print great
flag = 0 
for i in range(20):
    great-=1
    for j in l:
        if j==great:
            print "Second largest number is ",j
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag:
        break
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.